# Second order linear recurring sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let $\{u_{n}\}$ be a sequence such as $\forall n \in N; u_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}u_{n+1}+\frac{1}{2}u_{n}+1$

and $u_{1}$ and $u_{0}$ are fixed reals

I need to find the general term of this sequence.

I would have known how to find it if not for the "$+1$" there.

I noticed that if I could find only one sequence $\{V_{n}\}$ that checks the relation above, I could
easily find $\{u_{n}-V{n}\}$ and then proceed by finding $\{u_{n}\}$. I would love a hint about how I could find such a sequence. If not, the sequence itself wouldn't be bad.

Comment: $u_{n+3}=\frac{1}{2}u_{n+2}+\frac{1}{2}u_{n+1}+1$, then take the difference with the original

Comment: take this here $$u_n=c_1 \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n+c_2-\frac{2}{9} \left(2
   -3 n\right)$$

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind my asking, is there a sepecific way to find such sequences

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It is apparent you copied it from a calculator. Anyone would've noticed that $(-1)^{2n}=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Define another sequence

$$v_{n+1}=av_n+b$$

By self-substitution, see that

$$v_{n+2}=(a-x)v_{n+1}+axv_n+b(x+1)$$

Can you find suitable $a,b,x$ so that this sequence matches up with yours? And can you solve for $v_n$'s simpler form?

Comment: Got It. Thanks a lot for your amazing answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to approach the general problem

$$u_n=au_{n-1}+bu_{n-2}+c$$

Normally I would choose $u_n=f_n+p$ and calculate

$$p=\frac{c}{1-a-b}$$

However, in your case $a+b=1$ and the above solution doesn't work. Therefore you would take $u_n=f_n+pn$ and show that $p=\frac{c}{2-a}$ and solve for $f_n$ in the usual way and construct the solution for $u_n$.